# Minimize button loses window Linux Mint 19.1 Mate

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, window-management

I've installed Linux Mint 19.1 with the Mate desktop.

When I click on the minimize button on any window, the window disappears and I can't find how to return it to the screen.

Any running process, such as copy, will continue to run.

Comment: It seems you are asking people to direct you into using a graphical interface. Do you have a more specific question? What is exactly the problem into maximizing it again? If you do not want to keep running things there, why not closing it then?

Comment: It looks like you removed the window list applet from from your panel. I'm not running mate or gnome and cannot help you further, but try right clicking on the panel and then choose 'add to panel' and look for 'window list' or  'window switcher' or something like that. But you should be able to return the window to the screen with Alt-Tab, even without that.

Comment: That's it mosvy, adding Window List to the Panel fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint 19.1
Mate GUI

Issue:  Minimized applications keep running but disappear/don't show up in panel.

Suggestion:
Right click on the panel.
Select "Reset Panel"

Panel will reset, disappear and reappear.
Your minimized applications should now be visible again.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue (or perhaps the same issue). When I had several instances of a program open (firefox, for example), when minimized I could no longer get all of the instances to open back up when clicking on the task bar/panel/system tray. In addition, the nice preview screenshots did not pop up when I hovered over the icon in the task bar/panel. The instances can still be accessed by using **Alt+Tab** keystroke. Guided by Kaleb, I:

1. Right clicked on task bar/**system tray** blank space.
2. Selected **"Troubleshoot"**
3. Selected **"Looking Glass"**
4. Clicked on **Extensions Tab**
5. Right clicked on **"Grouped Window List"** Applet and hit **"Reload Code"**. Bingo.

I'm sure a full "Reset Panel" could work but if you have any custom settings, they might be lost.